# Looping inside the action listener and a different set text method

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a keypad and when I run it everything works. The problem is that I can only click 4 buttons at most then the click no longer works. Also every time I click the jtable doesn't populate it changes the letter each time.

```
JButton myButton1 = new JButton("<html><center> 2 <br /> ABC </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton2 = new JButton("<html><center> 3 <br /> DEF </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton3 = new JButton("<html><center> 4 <br /> GHI </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton4 = new JButton("<html><center> 5 <br /> JKL </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton5 = new JButton("<html><center> 6 <br /> MNO </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton6 = new JButton("<html><center> 7 <br /> PQRS </center> </html>");
    JButton myButton7;
    JButton myButton8;
    JButton myButton9;
    JButton myButton10;
    JButton myButton11;
    JLabel t1;
    JTextArea text1 = new JTextArea(2, 12);

    // CLASS INSTANCES AND OBJECTS

    myApplication() {
        setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        add(panel1);


//        JLabel t1 = new JLabel("");
//        panel1.add(t1);
        panel1.add(text1);
        panel1.setBounds(0, 130, 370, 40);
        Font textFont1 = new Font("Arial Bold", Font.BOLD, 18);

        JButton myButton = new JButton("1");
        myButton.setBounds(20, 190, 60, 60);

//        JButton myButton1 = new JButton("<html><center> 2 <br /> ABC </center> </html>");
        myButton1.setBounds(85, 190, 60, 60);
        myButton1.addActionListener(this);

//        JButton myButton2 = new JButton("<html><center> 3 <br /> DEF </center> </html>");
        myButton2.setBounds(150, 190, 60, 60);
        myButton2.addActionListener(this);


//        JButton myButton3 = new JButton("<html><center> 4 <br /> GHI </center> </html>");
        myButton3.setBounds(20, 260, 60, 60);
        myButton3.addActionListener(this);

//        JButton myButton4 = new JButton("<html><center> 5 <br /> JKL </center> </html>");
        myButton4.setBounds(85, 260, 60, 60);
        myButton4.addActionListener(this);

//        JButton myButton5 = new JButton("<html><center> 6 <br /> MNO </center> </html>");
        myButton5.setBounds(150, 260, 60, 60);
        myButton5.addActionListener(this);

//        JButton myButton6 = new JButton("<html><center> 7 <br /> PQRS </center> </html>");
        myButton6.setBounds(20, 330, 60, 60);
        myButton6.addActionListener(this);

        JButton myButton7 = new JButton("<html><center> 8 <br /> TUV </center> </html>");
        myButton7.setBounds(85, 330, 60, 60);

        JButton myButton8 = new JButton("<html><center> 9 <br /> WXYZ </center> </html>");
        myButton8.setBounds(150, 330, 60, 60);

        JButton myButton9 = new JButton("*");
        myButton9.setBounds(20, 400, 60, 60);

        JButton myButton10 = new JButton("0");
        myButton10.setBounds(85, 400, 60, 60);

        JButton myButton11 = new JButton("#");
        myButton11.setBounds(150, 400, 60, 60);

        add(myButton);
        add(myButton1);
        add(myButton2);
        add(myButton3);
        add(myButton4);
        add(myButton5);
        add(myButton6);
        add(myButton7);
        add(myButton8);
        add(myButton9);
        add(myButton10);
        add(myButton11);

        setTitle("Keypad");
        setSize(300, 500);
        setLocation(250, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private int clickCounter = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(e.getSource()== myButton1)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("2");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("A");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("B");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("C");
        if(e.getSource() == myButton2)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("3");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("D");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("E");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("F");
        if(e.getSource()== myButton3)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("4");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("G");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("H");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("I");
        if(e.getSource()== myButton4)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("5");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("J");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("K");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("L");
        if(e.getSource()==myButton5)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("6");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("M");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("N");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("O");
        if(e.getSource()== myButton6)
            if(clickCounter == 0)
               text1.setText("7");
            else if (clickCounter == 1)
               text1.setText("P");
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
                text1.setText("Q");
            else if(clickCounter == 3)
                text1.setText("R");
            else if(clickCounter == 4)
                text1.setText("S");

         clickCounter++;
    }   
}
```

Comment: setText() sets the entire text.   If you want to change / update (I assume this is supposed to be a cell-phone-type tap entry method), you've got to get the text, manipulate it, and put it back, or else use `append()`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like complete source at a glance, but it appears that you don't reset `clickCounter`, and therefore all your switch statements don't have anywhere to go when the counter gets to 4.

You don't ask about this, but I invite you to consider creating your own class, PhoneButton or something, that gets constructed to have its labels and its multi-click characters in an array or a string or something. Then you can process any click in the one place, and the entire list of if-then-else clauses will collapse into a few lines.